# LINQ NotSupportedOperation exception with Code First

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have a DbSet of Contacts and i am trying to execute the following query:

```
from contact in Context.Contacts 
where contact.Equals("given contact") 
select contact;
```

I get a `NotSupportedOperationException` that the system can't create non-scalar types like integers or string or GUIDs.
How can i execute the same query efficiently without retrieving all records from the database (eg. execute the filtering operation on the SQL server database) ?

**NOTE:** I have overridden the Equals method in the Contact type.

Comment: Entity Framework cannot see your overridden `Equals` method's implementation. What have you put in there? There may be a different way to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework cannot translate call to Equals in SQL code. Just do manual comparison of properties:

```
from contact in Context.Contacts 
where contact.Id == givenContact.Id
select contact;
```

Another (very slow) option - fetch all contacts from database and do comparison in-memory:

```
Context.Contacts.ToList().Where(contact.Equals(givenContact));
```

Comment: just one more thing, what is the thing that isn't creatable according the the exception >

Comment: @Sniffer sorry, didn't get what you mean

Comment: i meant the exception is saying that it can't create non-scalar types except for strings, int, guids, but i don't see where in the linq expression the system is trying to create any object ?

Comment: @Sniffer if you are doing second approach, then possibly you are missing `ToList()` in the middle